# How to implement Multi Select Drop Down with checkbox in Thymeleaf and display selected values to Spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

Multi Select Drop Down with check box example:

[image: Multi Select Drop Down with check box example]

How to convert below html code to thymeleaf to display in Spring  controller

Select Hobby Type :

```html
 <form action="#" th:action="@{/display}" method="POST">
 <div class="container">
 <p><strong>Select Hobbies(Multiple):</strong>
    <select id="multiple-hobbies" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="reading">Reading</option>
        <option value="cricket">Cricket</option>
        <option value="cooking">Cooking</option>
        <option value="movies">Watching Movies</option>
        <option value="music">Listening Music</option>
        <option value="sleeping">Sleeping</option>
    </select>
    </p>
     <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</div>
    
    
       </form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I implemented the following ,it works succesfully

[image: Multi Selected DropDown]
[image: After Submit DisplaySelected]

```html
   
 <form action="#" th:action="@{/display}"  th:object="${hobbyobj}" method="POST">
 <div class="container">
  
     <p><strong>Select Hobbies(Multiple):</strong>
    <select id="multiple-hobbies" th:field="*{hobbieslist}" multiple="multiple">
   
    <option th:each="hobby: ${predefinedhobbylist}"
              th:value="${hobby}" th:text="${hobby}">
    </select>
    </p>
     <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</div>    
   </form>
```

Controllers Class Implementation :

```
  @Controller
```

public class HobbiesController {

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HobbiesController.class);  


@GetMapping("/")
public ModelAndView smartphoneselect(Model model) {

     ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
     mav.setViewName("index.html");
     mav.addObject("hobbyobj",new Hobby());
     mav.addObject("predefinedhobbylist", gethobbieslist());
     return mav;
}

@PostMapping("/display")
public ModelAndView hobbiesdisplay(@ModelAttribute Hobby hobby) {

     ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

     mav.setViewName("display.html");

     logger.info("Hobbies Selected:"+hobby.getHobbieslist());

      mav.addObject("hobbiesselected",hobby.getHobbieslist()); 

      return mav;        
}

public List<String> gethobbieslist(){
    List<String> hobbieslist=new ArrayList<String>();
      hobbieslist.add("Reading");
      hobbieslist.add("Cricket"); 
      hobbieslist.add("Cooking");
      hobbieslist.add("Sleeping");
      hobbieslist.add("Waching Movies");
      hobbieslist.add("Listening Music");     

     return hobbieslist;
    }   
}
```

Model class implemented as :

```
public class Hobby {
private List<String> hobbieslist;

public List<String> getHobbieslist() {
    return hobbieslist;
}

public void setHobbieslist(List<String> hobbieslist) {
    this.hobbieslist = hobbieslist;
}
```

}

Comment: your solution does not work for me, could you please tell me where I am doing wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74173818/bootstrap-multiselect-with-thymeleaf?noredirect=1#comment130959849_74173818

Answer (score 0):

You can always send a list of strings with the selected values, and check if each value is contained in that list `#lists.contains(list, searchedValue)`. This list can be send from the Controller to the model, using `model.addAttributes("list", list)`. Now, on your model you can use `th:selected` to decided if the option should be selected. For example.

```
<select id="multiple-hobbies" multiple="multiple">
   <option th:selected="${#lists.contains(list, 'reading')}" value="reading">Reading</option>
   <option th:selected="${#lists.contains(list, 'cricket')}" value="cricket">Cricket</option>
   <!-- THE REST OF THE OPTIONS -->
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks ! With your comment i was able to  understand and implement ,please review my updated code and please tell me if it can be optimised or improved

Comment: Glad I was of help :)